# 3 gang box, code specifications

Tags: electrical

I have one 3 gang box of 44ci , and it needs to house the following wires:

- Three 14/2 wire for 3 switches.
- one 14/3 wire
- one Feed wire
- one jumper wire to feed another switch

Is this box deep enough and pass the inspection with above wires?

If not what is the alternative solution, a junction box  which will reduce jumper wire from 3 gang box?

Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by feed wire? If that is a 14-2 with ground you would add 4 more for the current carrying conductors and .5 for the ground over 4 grounds are now 1/4 the value this was a major change as for my entire career it has been 1x for all grounds. So you are at 38.5 still plenty of space left (the jumper is not counted). In reality it may be snug but is under the max fill so you are still good to go.

Comment: feed wire is 14/2 which brings power in the box. thanks

Comment: Your original question states 3 14-2  there is 3 hot and 3 neutrals for a total of 6 then the 14-3 there is 1 black hot 1 red hot and a white for +3 or a total of 9 current carrying conductors you then added by an edit the 14-2 that adds 2 more for 11 x 2 =22 plus the grounds 5 first 4 =1x or 2 then 1/4 or .5 for each additional 24.5 we add the switches at 2x or 4 for each one total 12 and we are up to 36.5 I threw in a clamp @1x or 2 for 38.5 grand total with the feeder still plenty of room. I just checked this matches the comment that had the feeder added and the answer matches the original

Comment: @Ed, actually feed wire and jumper wire were in same line. thats from confusion got created. so i separated feed wire from jumper wire. you are correct jumper wire doesn't count. thanks@

Comment: If an answer or comment is helpful we get our thanks from up votes the up arrow or accepting an answer the check mark this helps others to find an answer that worked for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change to the 2020 box fill calculation but you only have 4 grounds so your totals will be the same.
14 gauge is a 2cu inch multiplier.

So you have 9 current carrying conductors

4 grounds= 1

Each switch is a 2x so 6 (a total of 12 cu in)

16 x2 = 32 cu inch if there are clamps add 2 = 34cu in

so you should be fine You have a 10 cu inch safety.

Added with the addition of the feed wire:
With the addition of the feed wire 14-2 this adds 4.5 to the total for 38.5 cu inch
See comments for the complete calculations.
The box fill has changed and this change for 2020 increased the calculated fill by +.5 cu inch.

Comment: Thanks Ed. How did you count 9 conductors ?. there are total total five 14/2 and one 14/3 current carry conductors. so total conductor is 13 and 6 grounds. so total= 13 + 1(ground) + 6 ( switch)= 20X 2= 40+ 2= 42 ? is this correct ? thanks !